# Which InstanceType for rails elastic beanstalk development vs. production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We want to run both `development` and `production` instances on elastic beanstalk for our rails app.

Characteristics of `production` are:

- Low traffic
- Mostly CRUD
- Desire responsive pages (commercial endeavor, not hobby)

Database requirements (none on eb instance):

- Will use a multi-schema RDS instance
- `development` currently uses sqlite on eb instance
- Will perhaps use the same RDS instance for both `development` and `production`

Our `development` is currently a `t1.micro`, and clearly that isn't going to cut it even for development (login sometimes takes 60 seconds).

I will experiment, but would appreciate if anyone has any quick bits of advice for choosing an appropriate instance type for each env and which criteria/constraints are most meaningful for rails i.e. compute units.

Comment: FYI - moving the development instance from a t1.micro to an m1.small reduced deployment from ~8-19 minutes to ~3m 30s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2 cents - lean on the side of CPU over memory. CPU always helps; at the very least your app will compile assets and load into memory faster on deploys. I suggest starting with 2x c1.medium in production (in 2 different AZs for basic redundancy) and 1x m1.small in development.

Don't overthink the machine sizes, instead get the low hanging fruit right, namely: put your static assets on a CDN and implement fragment caching (stored in a dedicated redis or memcached node per environment).

If you've never done this before, New Relic Pro will likely give you a big head start identifying bottlenecks in your app.

Then get to load testing!

Also, please don't share your RDS instance between production and development. Isolate the two environments by giving each their own database.

Comment: Why separate RDS instead of just using different schemas on one consolidated RDS instance?

Comment: Reasons that come to mind immediately: a) you deploy a bug to development that causes a tight query loop that pegs RDS, b) you can safely load test your development cluster.

Comment: Load testing and bugs do make sense, might be a risk worth taking since we are minutes away from a rollback.  Since we are fully BDD/CI/CD, perhaps load testing periodically could mean spinning up an RDS (full size) for load testing, as opposed to incurring the ongoing cost of separate RDS all the time. Thoughts?

Comment: Is your CI inside AWS? What DB is it hitting? You might point CI at your development RDS to cut costs. I stand by keeping your production RDS separate from development is worth the money, though.

Comment: Also spinning up and down an RDS instance, seeding it, and toggling the RDS endpoint of your development cluster strikes me as tediously slow, but I haven't tried it, maybe it could work out nicely.

Comment: Also remember that a staging server can catch all sorts of problems you won't detect in BDD/CI. CD without a separate staging database scares the hell out of me.

Comment: Our CI runs on a separate local/disposable server.  When I mention `development`, I guess I'm really am thinking `staging` because our CD is literally going to be commit-to-deploy from the start (perhaps with a push button for staging-to-production using the bamboo deploy plan).  I really prefer our tests speak for themselves and CD direct to production.  I haven't put much thought into load testing yet.   All good points.